# Store configuration in a file like Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to accomplish the same thing Rails has done, to store configurations in rb files that are read by the application:

```
# routes.rb
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do |map|
  root :to => 'firstpage#index'
  resources :posts
```

In rails the methods "root" and "resources" are not defined in the object "main" scope.

That means that these methods are defined in either a module or a class. But how did they require the routes.rb file and used these methods from a class/module.

Because if I use "require" then these methods will be executed in the "main" scope, no matter where i run "require".

So how could you like Rails read this configuration file and run the methods defined in a class/module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your edit is that rails did not use `yield` or `Proc#call` in the `draw` method. It probably used [instance_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000334) or [class_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001650).

**(Edit)** For example, here is how the `draw` method could possibly be defined:

```
def draw(&blk)
  class << context = Object.new
    def root(p1, p2)
      # ...
    end
    def resources(p1, p2)
      # ...
    end
  end
  context.instance_eval(&blk)
end
```

Then, you could use it like this:

```
draw do
  root 2, 3
  resources 4, 5
end
```

Comment: you mean like this inside a module? instance_eval {yield}

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to effectively do this. `require` requires the contents files, period. It does not offer any other behavior. The `eval` solution is inferior to actually writing your Ruby files correctly so they contain their appropriate namespace information. If you want to include behavior in multiple classes, use modules.

Comment: Im not sure we have understood each other. Please read my updated post.

Answer (score 2):

Not really what I would consider as benign code, but that's how you could do it:

```
class A
  eval(File.read('yourfile.rb'))
end
```